# Android Studio Crash on Fedora 22

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fedora

I'm trying to run Android Studio in my Fedora22 machine. I've followed the instructions in the site, downloaded the zip, extracted it and ran studio.sh file.

It opens the Android Studio correctly, but after the download of components starts, it just closes without showing any dialogbox with the error.

As I'm running through the terminal, I saw the following error before the program gets closed:

> /home/mlima/android-studio/bin/studio.sh: line 188: 30819 Aborted
>   (core dumped) LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$IDE_BIN_HOME:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
>   "$JDK/bin/java" $AGENT "-Xbootclasspath/a:$IDE_HOME/lib/boot.jar"
>   -classpath "$CLASSPATH" $VM_OPTIONS "-Djb.vmOptionsFile=$VM_OPTIONS_FILES_USED"
>   "-XX:ErrorFile=$HOME/java_error_in_STUDIO_%p.log" -Djb.restart.code=88
>   -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio1.4 $IDE_PROPERTIES_PROPERTY $IDE_JVM_ARGS $REQUIRED_JVM_ARGS $MAIN_CLASS_NAME "$@"

My javac -version: **javac 1.8.0_60-debug**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to reinstall javac java -version is:
    java version "1.8.0_60"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)

And it work.
If this doesn't resolve the problem you have to find the way to set your environment HomePath variable points the current java sdk path.
Hope this can help, bye

Comment: Yea, the problem was with the java version. Just by downgrading the version back to 1.7.9 solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it has been helpful, bye!